# Out of memory exception in a C++/CX library used in a C# XAML Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, c++-cx

We have a C# XAML Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App.
This app is using a DLL implemented with C++/CX.
This DLL is allocating memory for a buffer (Can be >32MB).

We get sometimes an out of memory exception in the C++/cx DLL when the garbage collection of C# is to slow to free up unused memory.

How to handle this situation? We have enough memory, but it looks like the garbage colletor is to lazy to do his job early enough.

Comment: This could be caused by many different things. WP8.1 apps are restricted to 185 MB on low end phones, so anything that brings you over this limit will trigger an OOM exception. As it stands the question doesn't have enough data about how memory is used and the desired target.

Comment: You are right. This OOM exception is coming because of this 185MB limit. The garbage collector does wait to long to free unused memory. When at this point of time our C++ DLL allocates memory we get an OOM exception on the C++ side. Somehow the GC should consider there are non managed memory allocations in this C++ DLL. What is the right approach to handle this?

Comment: Is the offending allocation done in native code then?

Comment: Yes it is in the native code. But to be honest we also see this problem on the C# side. There we also do big allocations of WritableBitmaps. There the GC can also be to slow in free up the already unused WritableBitmaps and trigger OOM exceptions. Basically the users interaction with the app, can force us to allocate and free up WritableBitmaps and the native Buffers in a tight ~2 second loop. We tried to use GC.Collect (on the C# side) and GC.AddMemoryPressure (triggered from the C++ side) to come up with this problem. But we do not really know how to get the pattern right.